# Pyomo: Getting error for solving DAE. (KeyError: 2447832121968)

Tags: python, anaconda, pyomo

I am trying to solve DAE using pyomo. However, I am getting Keyerrors.The material balance equation in chemical engineering, which includes differential equations.

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo
from pyomo import dae
from pyomo import opt
import numpy as np
gasname = ['Gas1', 'Gas2']
x_init_gas1 = 0.2
x_init_gas2 = 0.8
x_init_list =  [x_init_gas1, x_init_gas2]
q_list = [1.2e-6, 5.0e-5]
x_init_dict = dict(zip(gasname, x_init_list))

q_dict = dict(zip(gasname, q_list))

area1_start = 0
area1_end = 100
ph_1, pl_1 = [3, 1]

U = 20

model = pyo.ConcreteModel(name='membrane sepalation')
model.gas_name = pyo.Set(initialize=gasname)
model.area1 = dae.ContinuousSet(bounds=(area1_start, area1_end))
discretizer_area1 = pyo.TransformationFactory('dae.finite_difference')
discretizer_area1.apply(model, wrt=model.area1)
area1_delta = list(model.area1)
model.area1_len = pyo.Set(initialize=range(0, len(area1_delta)))

model.ode_F1 = pyo.Var(model.gas_name, model.area1, domain=pyo.PositiveReals, initialize=(10))
model.F1_x = pyo.Var(model.gas_name, bounds=(0, 30), initialize=(10))
model.V1_x = pyo.Var(model.gas_name, bounds=(0, 30), initialize=(10))
model.G1_x = pyo.Var(model.gas_name, bounds=(0, 30), initialize=(10))


model.F1 = sum(model.F1_x[s] for s in gasname)
model.V1 = sum(model.V1_x[s] for s in gasname)
model.G1 = sum(model.G1_x[s] for s in gasname)

ph_1, pl_1 = [2.98, 1]

# 1
def const_F1_x(m, gas):
    return m.F1_x[gas] == x_init_dict[gas]*U

model.const_F1_x = pyo.Constraint(model.gas_name, rule=const_F1_x)

def const_F1_flow(m, gas):
    return m.F1_x[gas] == m.V1_x[gas] + m.G1_x[gas]

model.const_F1_flow = pyo.Constraint(model.gas_name, rule=const_F1_flow)

def const_module1_flow(m):
    return m.F1 == m.V1 + m.G1

model.const_module1_flow = pyo.Constraint(rule=const_module1_flow)

model.dF1_da = dae.DerivativeVar(model.ode_F1, wrt=model.area1, domain=pyo.PositiveReals)

def _ode_rule_module1(m, a, gas):
    if a == 0:
        return pyo.Constraint.Skip
    i = area1_delta.index(a)
    return m.dF1_da[gas, a] == -q_dict[gas]*((ph_1*m.ode_F1[gas, a]/sum(m.ode_F1[:, a]))-pl_1*((m.ode_F1[gas, a] - m.ode_F1[gas, area1_delta[i-1]])/(sum(m.ode_F1[:, a])-sum(m.ode_F1[:, area1_delta[i-1]])+1e-10)))

model.ode_rule_module1 = pyo.Constraint(model.area1, model.gas_name, rule=_ode_rule_module1)

def _ode_rule_module1_entry(m, gas):
    return m.F1_x[gas] == m.ode_F1[gas, area1_start]

model.ode_rule_module1_entry = pyo.Constraint(model.gas_name, rule=_ode_rule_module1_entry)

def _ode_rule_module1_exit(m, gas):
    return m.V1_x[gas] == m.ode_F1[gas, area1_end]

model.ode_rule_module1_exit = pyo.Constraint(model.gas_name, rule=_ode_rule_module1_exit)

def calc_objective(m):
    return m.V1_x[gasname[0]] / (U*x_init_gas1)
model.OBJ = pyo.Objective(rule=calc_objective, sense=pyo.maximize)
solver = opt.SolverFactory('ipopt')
solver.options["print_level"] = 1

res = solver.solve(model, tee=True)
print(model.display())
```

and, the error I got was

```
  File ~.py:154 in <module>
    res = solver.solve(model, tee=True)

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyomo\opt\base\solvers.py:570 in solve
    self._presolve(*args, **kwds)

  ~~~

  File pyomo\repn\plugins\ampl\ampl_.pyx:1039 in pyomo.repn.plugins.ampl.ampl_.ProblemWriter_nl._print_model_NL

  File pyomo\repn\plugins\ampl\ampl_.pyx:1033 in genexpr

  File pyomo\repn\plugins\ampl\ampl_.pyx:1033 in genexpr

KeyError: 2447832121968
```

The model.display() showed like that.

```
4 Set Declarations
    area1_len : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=Insertion
        Key  : Dimen : Domain : Size : Members
        None :     1 :    Any :   11 : {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
    gas_name : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=Insertion
        Key  : Dimen : Domain : Size : Members
        None :     1 :    Any :    2 : {'Gas1', 'Gas2'}
    ode_F1_index : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=True
        Key  : Dimen : Domain         : Size : Members
        None :     2 : gas_name*area1 :   22 : {('Gas1', 0), ('Gas1', 10.0), ('Gas1', 20.0), ('Gas1', 30.0), ('Gas1', 40.0), ('Gas1', 50.0), ('Gas1', 60.0), ('Gas1', 70.0), ('Gas1', 80.0), ('Gas1', 90.0), ('Gas1', 100), ('Gas2', 0), ('Gas2', 10.0), ('Gas2', 20.0), ('Gas2', 30.0), ('Gas2', 40.0), ('Gas2', 50.0), ('Gas2', 60.0), ('Gas2', 70.0), ('Gas2', 80.0), ('Gas2', 90.0), ('Gas2', 100)}
    ode_rule_module1_index : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=True
        Key  : Dimen : Domain         : Size : Members
        None :     2 : area1*gas_name :   22 : {(0, 'Gas1'), (0, 'Gas2'), (10.0, 'Gas1'), (10.0, 'Gas2'), (20.0, 'Gas1'), (20.0, 'Gas2'), (30.0, 'Gas1'), (30.0, 'Gas2'), (40.0, 'Gas1'), (40.0, 'Gas2'), (50.0, 'Gas1'), (50.0, 'Gas2'), (60.0, 'Gas1'), (60.0, 'Gas2'), (70.0, 'Gas1'), (70.0, 'Gas2'), (80.0, 'Gas1'), (80.0, 'Gas2'), (90.0, 'Gas1'), (90.0, 'Gas2'), (100, 'Gas1'), (100, 'Gas2')}

1 RangeSet Declarations
    area1_domain : Dimen=1, Size=Inf, Bounds=(0, 100)
        Key  : Finite : Members
        None :  False : [0..100]

4 Var Declarations
    F1_x : Size=2, Index=gas_name
        Key  : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
        Gas1 :     0 :    10 :    30 : False : False :  Reals
        Gas2 :     0 :    10 :    30 : False : False :  Reals
    G1_x : Size=2, Index=gas_name
        Key  : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
        Gas1 :     0 :    10 :    30 : False : False :  Reals
        Gas2 :     0 :    10 :    30 : False : False :  Reals
    V1_x : Size=2, Index=gas_name
        Key  : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
        Gas1 :     0 :    10 :    30 : False : False :  Reals
        Gas2 :     0 :    10 :    30 : False : False :  Reals
    ode_F1 : Size=22, Index=ode_F1_index
        Key            : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
           ('Gas1', 0) :     0 :    10 :  None : False : False : PositiveReals
        ('Gas1', 10.0) :     0 :    10 :  None : False : False : PositiveReals
        ('Gas1', 20.0) :     0 :    10 :  None : False : False : PositiveReals
        ('Gas1', 30.0) :     0 :    10 :  None : False : False : PositiveReals
        ('Gas1', 40.0) :     0 :    10 :  None : False : False : PositiveReals
        ('Gas1', 50.0) :     0 :    10 :  None : False : False : PositiveReals
        ('Gas1', 60.0) :     0 :    10 :  None : False : False : PositiveReals
        ('Gas1', 70.0) :     0 :    10 :  None : False : False : PositiveReals
        ('Gas1', 80.0) :     0 :    10 :  None : False : False : PositiveReals
        ('Gas1', 90.0) :     0 :    10 :  None : False : False : PositiveReals
         ('Gas1', 100) :     0 :    10 :  None : False : False : PositiveReals
           ('Gas2', 0) :     0 :    10 :  None : False : False : PositiveReals
        ('Gas2', 10.0) :     0 :    10 :  None : False : False : PositiveReals
        ('Gas2', 20.0) :     0 :    10 :  None : False : False : PositiveReals
        ('Gas2', 30.0) :     0 :    10 :  None : False : False : PositiveReals
        ('Gas2', 40.0) :     0 :    10 :  None : False : False : PositiveReals
        ('Gas2', 50.0) :     0 :    10 :  None : False : False : PositiveReals
        ('Gas2', 60.0) :     0 :    10 :  None : False : False : PositiveReals
        ('Gas2', 70.0) :     0 :    10 :  None : False : False : PositiveReals
        ('Gas2', 80.0) :     0 :    10 :  None : False : False : PositiveReals
        ('Gas2', 90.0) :     0 :    10 :  None : False : False : PositiveReals
         ('Gas2', 100) :     0 :    10 :  None : False : False : PositiveReals

1 Objective Declarations
    OBJ : Size=1, Index=None, Active=True
        Key  : Active : Sense    : Expression
        None :   True : maximize : 0.2557544757033248*V1_x[Gas1]

6 Constraint Declarations
    const_F1_flow : Size=2, Index=gas_name, Active=True
        Key  : Lower : Body                                   : Upper : Active
        Gas1 :   0.0 : F1_x[Gas1] - (V1_x[Gas1] + G1_x[Gas1]) :   0.0 :   True
        Gas2 :   0.0 : F1_x[Gas2] - (V1_x[Gas2] + G1_x[Gas2]) :   0.0 :   True
    const_F1_x : Size=2, Index=gas_name, Active=True
        Key  : Lower : Body       : Upper : Active
        Gas1 :  3.91 : F1_x[Gas1] :  3.91 :   True
        Gas2 : 15.64 : F1_x[Gas2] : 15.64 :   True
    const_module1_flow : Size=1, Index=None, Active=True
        Key  : Lower : Body                                                                          : Upper : Active
        None :   0.0 : F1_x[Gas1] + F1_x[Gas2] - (V1_x[Gas1] + V1_x[Gas2] + G1_x[Gas1] + G1_x[Gas2]) :   0.0 :   True
    ode_rule_module1 : Size=20, Index=ode_rule_module1_index, Active=True
        Key            : Lower : Body                                                                                                                                                                                                                             : Upper : Active
        (10.0, 'Gas1') :   0.0 :          dF1_da[Gas1,10.0] + 1.2e-06*(2.98*ode_F1[Gas1,10.0]/(ode_F1[Gas1,10.0] + ode_F1[Gas2,10.0]) - (ode_F1[Gas1,10.0] - ode_F1[Gas1,0])/(ode_F1[Gas1,10.0] + ode_F1[Gas2,10.0] - (ode_F1[Gas1,0] + ode_F1[Gas2,0]) + 1e-10)) :   0.0 :   True
        (10.0, 'Gas2') :   0.0 :            dF1_da[Gas2,10.0] + 5e-05*(2.98*ode_F1[Gas2,10.0]/(ode_F1[Gas1,10.0] + ode_F1[Gas2,10.0]) - (ode_F1[Gas2,10.0] - ode_F1[Gas2,0])/(ode_F1[Gas1,10.0] + ode_F1[Gas2,10.0] - (ode_F1[Gas1,0] + ode_F1[Gas2,0]) + 1e-10)) :   0.0 :   True
        (20.0, 'Gas1') :   0.0 : dF1_da[Gas1,20.0] + 1.2e-06*(2.98*ode_F1[Gas1,20.0]/(ode_F1[Gas1,20.0] + ode_F1[Gas2,20.0]) - (ode_F1[Gas1,20.0] - ode_F1[Gas1,10.0])/(ode_F1[Gas1,20.0] + ode_F1[Gas2,20.0] - (ode_F1[Gas1,10.0] + ode_F1[Gas2,10.0]) + 1e-10)) :   0.0 :   True
        (20.0, 'Gas2') :   0.0 :   dF1_da[Gas2,20.0] + 5e-05*(2.98*ode_F1[Gas2,20.0]/(ode_F1[Gas1,20.0] + ode_F1[Gas2,20.0]) - (ode_F1[Gas2,20.0] - ode_F1[Gas2,10.0])/(ode_F1[Gas1,20.0] + ode_F1[Gas2,20.0] - (ode_F1[Gas1,10.0] + ode_F1[Gas2,10.0]) + 1e-10)) :   0.0 :   True
        (30.0, 'Gas1') :   0.0 : dF1_da[Gas1,30.0] + 1.2e-06*(2.98*ode_F1[Gas1,30.0]/(ode_F1[Gas1,30.0] + ode_F1[Gas2,30.0]) - (ode_F1[Gas1,30.0] - ode_F1[Gas1,20.0])/(ode_F1[Gas1,30.0] + ode_F1[Gas2,30.0] - (ode_F1[Gas1,20.0] + ode_F1[Gas2,20.0]) + 1e-10)) :   0.0 :   True
        (30.0, 'Gas2') :   0.0 :   dF1_da[Gas2,30.0] + 5e-05*(2.98*ode_F1[Gas2,30.0]/(ode_F1[Gas1,30.0] + ode_F1[Gas2,30.0]) - (ode_F1[Gas2,30.0] - ode_F1[Gas2,20.0])/(ode_F1[Gas1,30.0] + ode_F1[Gas2,30.0] - (ode_F1[Gas1,20.0] + ode_F1[Gas2,20.0]) + 1e-10)) :   0.0 :   True
        (40.0, 'Gas1') :   0.0 : dF1_da[Gas1,40.0] + 1.2e-06*(2.98*ode_F1[Gas1,40.0]/(ode_F1[Gas1,40.0] + ode_F1[Gas2,40.0]) - (ode_F1[Gas1,40.0] - ode_F1[Gas1,30.0])/(ode_F1[Gas1,40.0] + ode_F1[Gas2,40.0] - (ode_F1[Gas1,30.0] + ode_F1[Gas2,30.0]) + 1e-10)) :   0.0 :   True
        (40.0, 'Gas2') :   0.0 :   dF1_da[Gas2,40.0] + 5e-05*(2.98*ode_F1[Gas2,40.0]/(ode_F1[Gas1,40.0] + ode_F1[Gas2,40.0]) - (ode_F1[Gas2,40.0] - ode_F1[Gas2,30.0])/(ode_F1[Gas1,40.0] + ode_F1[Gas2,40.0] - (ode_F1[Gas1,30.0] + ode_F1[Gas2,30.0]) + 1e-10)) :   0.0 :   True
        (50.0, 'Gas1') :   0.0 : dF1_da[Gas1,50.0] + 1.2e-06*(2.98*ode_F1[Gas1,50.0]/(ode_F1[Gas1,50.0] + ode_F1[Gas2,50.0]) - (ode_F1[Gas1,50.0] - ode_F1[Gas1,40.0])/(ode_F1[Gas1,50.0] + ode_F1[Gas2,50.0] - (ode_F1[Gas1,40.0] + ode_F1[Gas2,40.0]) + 1e-10)) :   0.0 :   True
        (50.0, 'Gas2') :   0.0 :   dF1_da[Gas2,50.0] + 5e-05*(2.98*ode_F1[Gas2,50.0]/(ode_F1[Gas1,50.0] + ode_F1[Gas2,50.0]) - (ode_F1[Gas2,50.0] - ode_F1[Gas2,40.0])/(ode_F1[Gas1,50.0] + ode_F1[Gas2,50.0] - (ode_F1[Gas1,40.0] + ode_F1[Gas2,40.0]) + 1e-10)) :   0.0 :   True
        (60.0, 'Gas1') :   0.0 : dF1_da[Gas1,60.0] + 1.2e-06*(2.98*ode_F1[Gas1,60.0]/(ode_F1[Gas1,60.0] + ode_F1[Gas2,60.0]) - (ode_F1[Gas1,60.0] - ode_F1[Gas1,50.0])/(ode_F1[Gas1,60.0] + ode_F1[Gas2,60.0] - (ode_F1[Gas1,50.0] + ode_F1[Gas2,50.0]) + 1e-10)) :   0.0 :   True
        (60.0, 'Gas2') :   0.0 :   dF1_da[Gas2,60.0] + 5e-05*(2.98*ode_F1[Gas2,60.0]/(ode_F1[Gas1,60.0] + ode_F1[Gas2,60.0]) - (ode_F1[Gas2,60.0] - ode_F1[Gas2,50.0])/(ode_F1[Gas1,60.0] + ode_F1[Gas2,60.0] - (ode_F1[Gas1,50.0] + ode_F1[Gas2,50.0]) + 1e-10)) :   0.0 :   True
        (70.0, 'Gas1') :   0.0 : dF1_da[Gas1,70.0] + 1.2e-06*(2.98*ode_F1[Gas1,70.0]/(ode_F1[Gas1,70.0] + ode_F1[Gas2,70.0]) - (ode_F1[Gas1,70.0] - ode_F1[Gas1,60.0])/(ode_F1[Gas1,70.0] + ode_F1[Gas2,70.0] - (ode_F1[Gas1,60.0] + ode_F1[Gas2,60.0]) + 1e-10)) :   0.0 :   True
        (70.0, 'Gas2') :   0.0 :   dF1_da[Gas2,70.0] + 5e-05*(2.98*ode_F1[Gas2,70.0]/(ode_F1[Gas1,70.0] + ode_F1[Gas2,70.0]) - (ode_F1[Gas2,70.0] - ode_F1[Gas2,60.0])/(ode_F1[Gas1,70.0] + ode_F1[Gas2,70.0] - (ode_F1[Gas1,60.0] + ode_F1[Gas2,60.0]) + 1e-10)) :   0.0 :   True
        (80.0, 'Gas1') :   0.0 : dF1_da[Gas1,80.0] + 1.2e-06*(2.98*ode_F1[Gas1,80.0]/(ode_F1[Gas1,80.0] + ode_F1[Gas2,80.0]) - (ode_F1[Gas1,80.0] - ode_F1[Gas1,70.0])/(ode_F1[Gas1,80.0] + ode_F1[Gas2,80.0] - (ode_F1[Gas1,70.0] + ode_F1[Gas2,70.0]) + 1e-10)) :   0.0 :   True
        (80.0, 'Gas2') :   0.0 :   dF1_da[Gas2,80.0] + 5e-05*(2.98*ode_F1[Gas2,80.0]/(ode_F1[Gas1,80.0] + ode_F1[Gas2,80.0]) - (ode_F1[Gas2,80.0] - ode_F1[Gas2,70.0])/(ode_F1[Gas1,80.0] + ode_F1[Gas2,80.0] - (ode_F1[Gas1,70.0] + ode_F1[Gas2,70.0]) + 1e-10)) :   0.0 :   True
        (90.0, 'Gas1') :   0.0 : dF1_da[Gas1,90.0] + 1.2e-06*(2.98*ode_F1[Gas1,90.0]/(ode_F1[Gas1,90.0] + ode_F1[Gas2,90.0]) - (ode_F1[Gas1,90.0] - ode_F1[Gas1,80.0])/(ode_F1[Gas1,90.0] + ode_F1[Gas2,90.0] - (ode_F1[Gas1,80.0] + ode_F1[Gas2,80.0]) + 1e-10)) :   0.0 :   True
        (90.0, 'Gas2') :   0.0 :   dF1_da[Gas2,90.0] + 5e-05*(2.98*ode_F1[Gas2,90.0]/(ode_F1[Gas1,90.0] + ode_F1[Gas2,90.0]) - (ode_F1[Gas2,90.0] - ode_F1[Gas2,80.0])/(ode_F1[Gas1,90.0] + ode_F1[Gas2,90.0] - (ode_F1[Gas1,80.0] + ode_F1[Gas2,80.0]) + 1e-10)) :   0.0 :   True
         (100, 'Gas1') :   0.0 :        dF1_da[Gas1,100] + 1.2e-06*(2.98*ode_F1[Gas1,100]/(ode_F1[Gas1,100] + ode_F1[Gas2,100]) - (ode_F1[Gas1,100] - ode_F1[Gas1,90.0])/(ode_F1[Gas1,100] + ode_F1[Gas2,100] - (ode_F1[Gas1,90.0] + ode_F1[Gas2,90.0]) + 1e-10)) :   0.0 :   True
         (100, 'Gas2') :   0.0 :          dF1_da[Gas2,100] + 5e-05*(2.98*ode_F1[Gas2,100]/(ode_F1[Gas1,100] + ode_F1[Gas2,100]) - (ode_F1[Gas2,100] - ode_F1[Gas2,90.0])/(ode_F1[Gas1,100] + ode_F1[Gas2,100] - (ode_F1[Gas1,90.0] + ode_F1[Gas2,90.0]) + 1e-10)) :   0.0 :   True
    ode_rule_module1_entry : Size=2, Index=gas_name, Active=True
        Key  : Lower : Body                        : Upper : Active
        Gas1 :   0.0 : F1_x[Gas1] - ode_F1[Gas1,0] :   0.0 :   True
        Gas2 :   0.0 : F1_x[Gas2] - ode_F1[Gas2,0] :   0.0 :   True
    ode_rule_module1_exit : Size=2, Index=gas_name, Active=True
        Key  : Lower : Body                          : Upper : Active
        Gas1 :   0.0 : V1_x[Gas1] - ode_F1[Gas1,100] :   0.0 :   True
        Gas2 :   0.0 : V1_x[Gas2] - ode_F1[Gas2,100] :   0.0 :   True

1 ContinuousSet Declarations
    area1 : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=Sorted
        Key  : Dimen : Domain   : Size : Members
        None :     1 : [0..100] :   11 : {0, 10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 40.0, 50.0, 60.0, 70.0, 80.0, 90.0, 100}

1 DerivativeVar Declarations
    dF1_da : Size=22, Index=ode_F1_index
        Key            : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
           ('Gas1', 0) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : PositiveReals
        ('Gas1', 10.0) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : PositiveReals
        ('Gas1', 20.0) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : PositiveReals
        ('Gas1', 30.0) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : PositiveReals
        ('Gas1', 40.0) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : PositiveReals
        ('Gas1', 50.0) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : PositiveReals
        ('Gas1', 60.0) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : PositiveReals
        ('Gas1', 70.0) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : PositiveReals
        ('Gas1', 80.0) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : PositiveReals
        ('Gas1', 90.0) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : PositiveReals
         ('Gas1', 100) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : PositiveReals
           ('Gas2', 0) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : PositiveReals
        ('Gas2', 10.0) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : PositiveReals
        ('Gas2', 20.0) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : PositiveReals
        ('Gas2', 30.0) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : PositiveReals
        ('Gas2', 40.0) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : PositiveReals
        ('Gas2', 50.0) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : PositiveReals
        ('Gas2', 60.0) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : PositiveReals
        ('Gas2', 70.0) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : PositiveReals
        ('Gas2', 80.0) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : PositiveReals
        ('Gas2', 90.0) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : PositiveReals
         ('Gas2', 100) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : PositiveReals

18 Declarations: gas_name area1_domain area1 area1_len ode_F1_index ode_F1 F1_x V1_x G1_x const_F1_x const_F1_flow const_module1_flow dF1_da ode_rule_module1_index ode_rule_module1 ode_rule_module1_entry ode_rule_module1_exit OBJ
```

[Similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71264741/pyomo-getting-keyerror-2472563968992) existed before, but I could not understand them.

Could you please help me solve it? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're applying the discretization transformation before declaring all the `DerivativeVar` components in your model. The discretization transformation discretizes the `ContinuousSets` in the model and also adds discretization equations to the model for every `DerivativeVar` that has been declared so it is crucial that the transformation not be applied until after all `DerivativeVar` components have been declared.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I am trying to adapt it in my context.